Groupby and sum the max in DAX
I have a sample data as below and I would like to create a powerbi card. The dax code should first groupby based on Source and sum the measure of max(FYandFW). How to get around with this ?
Source  FYandFW num 
Company A   202453  **
Company A   202452  
Company A   202451  
Company B   202501  
Company B   202502  **
Company B   202453  

Expected Answer Summing measures for **


What does the final result look like?

it should be single number. which is the sum for Company A and Company B when FYandFW is max for each.

Here is one approach:
Your Measure = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(YourTable[Source]),
    CALCULATE(
      [your sum measure],
      TOPN(1, CALCULATETABLE(YourTable), [FYandFW num], DESC)
    )
  )


the code is not working properly cause Sum is a measure. should i open another question ?

See updated answer
